# Meaning of "bloody" in "Full Bloody Italian"

Tags: meaning

I have once seen somebody in a chat expanding *FBI* (*Federal Bureau of Investigations*) as *Full Bloody Italian*, after I said I was from Italy.

While I can understand to what the person who wrote it was referring, I don't understand what *bloody* would mean in the phrase.

- What does *full bloody* mean in *full bloody Italian*?
- Should *blooded* be used instead of *bloody*, in this case?
- Would *full blooded Italian* be understood as *who completely has Italian blood*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does full bloody mean in full bloody Italian?

I'm not sure of the intent, but possibly the word is used as an intensifier or mild expletive in the phrase. I imagine the word chosen would be different if it were the FFI. :)

> Should blooded be used instead of bloody, in this case?

If it were meant as an intensifier *(bloody Italians!)*, no.

> Would full blooded Italian be understood as who completely has Italian blood?

Yes. Full-blooded Italian would mean someone whose ancestry is completely Italian — or at least someone who is steeped in and fully exhibits the Italian culture.

Answer (score 5):

I am sure it is a misprint of full-blooded Italians which is a [tag team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Blooded_Italians)

Full-blooded: *Of unmixed ancestry; purebred.*

Update: There is no such thing as Full Bloody Italian unless it is a mistake or a deliberate slur/joke on the Full-blooded. Bloody is a swear word so Bloody Italian would be said by someone annoyed by Italians. I have never heard that there would be a lot of Italians in FBI either. Historically a lot of Irish on the NYPD...
Try http://www.google.com/search?q=fbi+full+italian to see there is no popular usage of Bloody in that context

Comment: Actually, it was referring to _Federal Bureau of Investigations_.

Comment: A misspelling of *full-blooded Italian* it may well be, but it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a wrestling team.

Comment: There is a wrestling team called F.B.I., full-blooded Italians. Does sound very much like what is asked: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Blooded_Italians

Comment: I suppose a full bloody Italian is an Italian person covered in blood, who just happens to have recently had a big meal.

Answer (score 4):

I believe in this case that "bloody" is intended as the mild oath (a contraction of "by our lady", if memory serves).  "Full bloody Italian" then would roughly translate to "completely g*ddamned well Italian".