# Meaning of "Bloody Beautiful"

Tags: meaning

This [article](https://magazine.cucumbertown.com/the-beginners-guide-to-composition-in-food-photography-how-to-transform-your-food-photos-from-good-39613ab78bf2#.zh17xvvs6) has the title "How to Transform Your Food Photos from Good to Bloody Beautiful". What does "Bloody Beautiful" mean?

Comment: Cf. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11647/meaning-of-bloody-in-full-bloody-italian

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Bloody* in this context is an adverb to add degree to the adjective *beautiful*. It's not common in American English but is very common in British English. It's considered a mild swear word, and thus adds more emphasis than a more benign word like *very*.

The author is promising to help your photos transform from "good" to "beautiful" -- but not just beautiful: *extremely* beautiful.

For example, see: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bloody

Answer (score 11):

It means **"really beautiful"**. "Bloody" simply serves as an intensifier.

> Bloody: Used as an intensive (Chiefly British Slang)

([American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bloody)

On a separate note, I suspect the reason the author put "bloody" next to "beautiful" is because of alliteration:

> alliteration: the use of several words together that **begin with the same sound or letter** in order to make a **special effect**

(Longman Dictionary)

Comment: Not just the alliteration, but also the ironic contrast.